# how to expose cpu flag with virt-manager

Tags: cpu, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

I want to know if there is a way to expose some cpu flag (mssse3 , mssse4.1) using Virt-Manager for my KVMs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not in virt-manager directly but you could type `host-passthrough` into the CPU type field which would expose all HVs CPU features.

Another option would be to manually edit the guests XML definition using virsh.

[image]